# How to change the color of horizontal line on a wiki page?

Tags: css, wiki, wikipedia

In wiki you can add horizontal line just by adding "----" in the text you enter.
I just couldn't find what CSS section controls it. (And no, it's not "hr")

Comment: Hello, could you give us the source code of the generated html?

Comment: OK. It IS "<hr />" in the generated html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to comment from  enguerran I've checked it and it *is* 'hr' tag. But I've tried wrong properties. This one works:

`hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #E58E9F;
}`

Comment: Web Developer addin for Firefox is great for this and many other web/css/etc things and is pretty tight with regards to bugs and bloat.  Give it a try as well.

Answer (score 1):

To apply this change to all wiki skins, edit the wiki page `[[Mediawiki:Common.css]]`, and put your `hr { }` CSS in there.